# Batch operation to all matrices stored in a n-dimensional numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of size (4, 4, 6890), which basically stores contains 6890 4x4 matrices. I need to invert all of them and I am currently doing in a loop, which I know is a bad practice

```
for i in range(0, T.shape[2]):
    T_inv[:,:,i] = np.linalg.inv(T[:,:,i])
```

How can I do it with a single call?

Comment: Why do you store it as a 4x4x68690? Shouldn't it make more sense to store it as a 68690x4x4?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I did not take that decision, it's a dataset I got already packed like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`np.linalg.inv` will do it, but you need to rearrange your axes:

```
 T_inv = np.moveaxis(np.linalg.inv(np.moveaxis(T, -1, 0)), 0, -1)
```

Might be better to just construct `T` so that `T.shape = (68690, 4, 4)`.  It will help with broadcasting as well.

Comment: It turns out that both inv and pinv works pretty good in batch format (num_batches, mtrix_axis0, matrix_axis1)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do it with `numpy`, but check this out:

```
[ A 0 0 ]   [ A^(-1)    0        0   ]   [ I 0 0 ]
[ 0 B 0 ] * [   0     B^(-1)     0   ] = [ 0 I 0 ]
[ 0 0 C ]   [   0       0     C^(-1) ]   [ 0 0 I ]
```

`A`,`B`,`C` being matrices of the same size (for example 4x4), and `A^(-1)`, `B^(-1)`, `C^(-1)`, being their inverses. `I` is a unity matrix.

So, what does this tell us? We can construct a large **sparse block-diagonal** matrix with all the sub-matrices (4x4) on diagonal, take the inverse of that large matrix, and just read-out the sub-matrices' inverses off diagonal blocks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure inverting a big matrix is not computationally easier than inverting a bunch of small matrices.  Not to mention a `274760 x 274760` matrix will cause a `MemoryError` all by itself before you even try to invert it.

Comment: That's why I wrote **sparse** matrix. I'm not sure if `numpy` is clever enough to handle it. In general, though, diagonal, or near-diagonal matrices can be inverted efficiently.

Comment: I was just trying to show in my answer how it's possible (mathematically) to shift calculation of inverses from a loop in `python` to a loop in `numpy` (classical vectorization). Of course, predicated on the assumption `numpy` knows how to inverse a block-diagonal matrix.

Comment: The "clever" way to invert sparse block-diagonal matrices *is* to invert the blocks - which we're already doing.  You've got the trick backwards.